# get multiple words after a specific word of HTML using linux/unix scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

i have a file 'movie.html' :

```
<html>
<head><title>Index of /Data/Movies/Hollywood/2016_2017/</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /Data/Movies/Hollywood/2016_2017/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="1%20Buck%20%282017%29/">1 Buck (2017)/</a>                                     25-Nov-2019 10:25       -
<a href="1%20Mile%20to%20You%20%282017%29/">1 Mile to You (2017)/</a>                              25-Nov-2019 10:26       -
<a href="1%20Night%20%282016%29/">1 Night (2016)/</a>                                    25-Nov-2019 10:27       -
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

I want to get multiple word with pipe delimited like this:

```
title | link
1 Buck (2017) | 1%20Buck%20%282017%29/
1 Mile to You (2017) | 1%20Mile%20to%20You%20%282017%29/
1 Night (2016) | 1%20Night%20%282016%29/
```

I tried this code:

```
awk -F'[><]' 'BEGIN{ print "title","link" } /%29/ {print $3,$2}' movie.html > output.txt
```

but the output isn't as my expectation please help me, i am still a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing html with regex is not advised for several reasons (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/12957340), but here is one potential solution:

```
awk -F'[<>/"]' 'BEGIN{ print "title | link" }; /\(.*\)/ {print $6 " | " $3}' movie.html
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. I prefer to this with `match` function.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" | "
  print "title | link"
}
match($0,/^<a href="[^"]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)
  match($0,/>.*<\/a>/)
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-6),val
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                     ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  OFS=" | "                                ##Setting OFS as space | space here.
  print "title | link"                     ##Printing title space | space link here.
}
match($0,/^<a href="[^"]*/){               ##Using match to match regex from starting of line <a href=" till " comes.
  val=substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)        ##Creating val which has sub string of matched above text, making it as per OP needs here.
  match($0,/>.*<\/a>/)                     ##Using match to match from > till </a> here.
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-6),val  ##Printing current matched sub string(by above match function) and val value here.
}
' Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

If `ed` is available/acceptable and you understand the risk of using non html parser to parse hmtl files.

`script.ed`

```
0a
title | link
.
p
g/^<a href=.\{1,\}/s/^.\{1,\}="//\
s/\/[[:blank:]]*<\/a>.*$//\
s/">/ /\
s/^\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \(.\{1,\}\)/\2 | \1/p
Q
```

Then

```
ed -s file.html < script.ed
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, I think you could get the processed lines with `grep` and then use `awk` format the output content.

```
grep -oP 'href="([^".]*)">([^</.]*)' movie.html | awk -F'[">]' 'BEGIN{print "title | link"}{print $4" | "$2}'
```

`grep` will get the lines like below:

```
href="1%20Buck%20%282017%29/">1 Buck (2017)
href="1%20Mile%20to%20You%20%282017%29/">1 Mile to You (2017)
href="1%20Night%20%282016%29/">1 Night (2016)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `sub()` and `gsub()` functions to the code:

```
awk -F'[><]' 'BEGIN{ print "title","|", "link" } /%29/ {sub(/\//, " |", $3);gsub(/^a href="|"$/, "", $2);print $3,$2}' file
title | link
1 Buck (2017) | 1%20Buck%20%282017%29/
1 Mile to You (2017) | 1%20Mile%20to%20You%20%282017%29/
1 Night (2016) | 1%20Night%20%282016%29/
```

With `file > output`:

```
awk -F'[><]' 'BEGIN{ print "title","|", "link" } /%29/ {sub(/\//, " |", $3);gsub(/^a href="|"$/, "", $2);print $3,$2}' file > output.txt
```